# Questions regarding the elements of vector space spin representations act on

Tags: terminology, representation-theory, group-representations, spinors

Elements of vector space spin-$1/2$ representations act on are spinors.
What about half-integers in general?
And what about integer spins?
Do spin-$0$,$1$ reps always act on vectors?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I will discuss the representation theory of SO(3), 3-dim rotation group in 3-dimensional space which is the non-relativistic case. The relativistic case, the representation theory of the Lorentz group, is substantially more complicated.

Spinor, scalar and vector representations in 3-dim space can be constructed from the generators of the Lie-algebra of SO(3). The generators of the corresponding Lie-algebra fulfill the following commutation relations: ($a,b,c=1,\ldots, 3)$

$[J_a, J_b]=i\epsilon_{abc} J_c$. (1)

The generators $J_a$ are here defined as hermitian as it is usually done in physics. Summation over double appearing indices is assumed (here index $c$).

(1) is an algebraic abstract relation, and representation theory searches for all set of 3 matrices, which can fulfill this relation.  The irreducible  (=the most basic, see more at the end of this post) representations are each characterized by one number $j$, the weight of the representation which can have all half-integer values $j=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots$. The weight $j$ allows us to know the dimension of the representation which is $2j+1$. So $j=\frac{1}{2}$ corresponds to 2-dim non-relativistic spinors which have 2 components. $j=0$ corresponds to the scalar representation, which is trivial and only has 1 component, and indeed $j=1$ corresponds to a 3-dim. representation which is realized by 3x3 matrices acting on 3-dim. vectors.

The representation theory of SO(3) shows that the 3 2x2 Pauli-matrices $\vec{\sigma}$ fulfill the commutation relations (1).  The corresponding Lie-group representation is then given by: ($\vec{\alpha}$ is the rotation vector with direction $\vec{\alpha}$ and angle $|\vec{\alpha}|$).

$D^{(j=\frac{1}{2})}(\vec{\alpha})=exp(-i\vec{\alpha}\vec{J})$ with $\vec{J}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma}$

$D^{(\frac{1}{2})}(\vec{\alpha})$ is  2x2 and can act on 2-dimensional objects called spinors in 3-dimensional space.

$D^{(0)}(\vec{\alpha})$ however is trivial, it is just the number 1, as a scalar does not change under rotations of SO(3). The matrices of the Lie-algebra (1) are just zero 0.

$D^{(1)}(\vec{\alpha})$ are 3-dim rotation matrices which act on 3-dim. vectors.
The corresponding members of the Lie-algebra are 3x3-matrices $\vec{J}$ which fulfill (1) and have the following form:

$(J_1)_{\mu\nu}= -\epsilon_{1\mu\nu}, (J_2)_{\mu\nu}= -\epsilon_{2\mu\nu}$, $(J_3)_{\mu\nu}= -\epsilon_{3\mu\nu}$.

I recall that $\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}$ is the completely antisymmetrical Levi-Civita-Symbol, which is 1 if $(\lambda\mu\nu)$ is an even permutation of (1,2,3), it has the value -1 if $(\lambda\mu\nu)$ is a odd permutation of (1,2,3) and is zero if any index in $(\lambda\mu\nu)$ appears twice or three times.

Higher representations $j=\frac{3}{2},2, \ldots$ can be constructed in a similar way.

All here presented Lie-group representations realize 3-dim. rotations corresponding to the type of object (scalar, spinor, vector etc.)

Representation theory distinguishes  between reducible and irreducible representations, the irreducible ones are the most basic ones, and the reducible ones can be built up of combinations of irreducible representations. But the 3 representations discussed here (spinor, scalar, vector) are all irreducible.